# Is there a way to import custom Reinforcement Learning Models into Unity?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, deep-learning

Unity provides two RL algorithms to train agents: PPO and SAC.

I have been searching for weeks now on how to write my own algorithms and only found a mention of a gym-unity wrapper that wraps Unity Environments and I could just write my algorithms using Gym. This wrapper has 0 useful documentation so I don't have anywhere to start.

My questions are:
(1) How can I import custom-written RL models into unity?
(2) Is there a better documentation for the wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at my repository [genetic-unity](https://github.com/valentinmace/genetic-unity) that implements evolutionary algorithms using the ML-Agent package.

I did not use their implemented agents (PPO and SAC) and I just used the interface between Unity and python to code my own algorithms, which is what you're looking for if I understand correctly.

You could start by looking at the `genetic_algorithm.py` file to see how I handle the Unity environment.

However you should note that this work was made 9 months ago and the ML-Agent framework changes at a fast pace, maybe you will need to adapt a little bit.

Comment: I will definitely take a loot at it since resources are very scarce on that subject. Thanks a mill my friend, any more feedback and resources are very welcomed!

Comment: Yeah I encountered the same problem, resources are not very easy to find if you just want to use their environment API with ML-Agent. Feel free to ask me if you have questions. Also don't forget to upvote or mark as solved if it was helpful to you :)

Comment: I reached out to you privately by mail to ask about more sources and compliment you on your work and have a little more in depth discussion :)